# How to hide character range with CodeMirror?

Tags: codemirror

I'm not sure what I'm asking for is possible, but here we go:

I'm trying to create an editor that allows JS style interpolation in text. The fields syntax-wise should be exactly what goes into an expression like this:

```
`Hello ${name} how are you doing on this ${weather} day?`
```

But without the ticks, so this is what the user should see:

```
Hello ${name} how are you doing on this ${weather} day?
```

My first thought was to simply hide the first and last character in the editor and keep syntax highlighting, tokenizing, everything the same, and I'm good to go. Is this possible to do with CodeMirror?